# .NET Exception and Errors fields

Tags: c#, exception

I use third-party component (SendGrid) and this component throws Exception:

```
        var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
        myMessage.AddTo(element.Receiver);
        myMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(element.SenderEmail, element.SenderName);
        myMessage.Subject = element.Subject;
        myMessage.Text = element.Body;
        myMessage.Html = element.Body;

        string sendGridApiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendGridApiKey"];
        var transportWeb = new SendGrid.Web(sendGridApiKey);
try
{
    await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

debugger says, that "ex" has field Errors with array of errors and ex.Message='Bad Request Check `Errors` for a list of errors returned by the API.'

But if I try to write something:

```
var x = ex.Errors;
```

It says

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1061  'Exception' does not contain a definition for 'Errors' and no extension method 'Errors' accepting a first argument of type 'Exception' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) SendGridEmailService

How it's implemented and (as I understand, there is an exception from unknown namespace) how to know this exception?

Comment: put an breakpoint into the catch statement then with your mouse check the exact type of ex varaible.

Comment: @OlegSh you will need to post the full code block for where you have this code.. also the error message is telling you what the error is ..

Comment: @MethodMan but I wrote error message!

Comment: @CodeNotFound, I don't see http://www.magicscreenshot.com/jpg/oHQFpYKGMUA.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception probably doesn't contain Errors field, so you are getting compilation errors. ex itself is an instance of some subclass of Exception, but the compiler doesn't know which, it only know it's assignable to Exception as you declare "Exception ex". So the solution is to catch more specific exception, which is also a good practice, as by catching the general Exception, you are catching all the exceptions, which is what you usually don't want.

If you want to get the actual type of ex at runtime, you can use ex.GetType(), but you should be able to see it in a debugger.

Comment: ex.GetType() . Thank you, exactly what I want.

Comment: Ok then! Glad I could help.

Comment: But the method with the debugger really should work. See this screenshot by @Scott Chamberlain http://i.stack.imgur.com/bUsQv.png

Answer (score 2):

I found this online after a little searching, looks like you want `InvalidApiRequestException`

```
try
{
    await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
}
catch (InvalidApiRequestException ex)
{
}
```

if you still want to try and catch all exceptions, you can do something like:

```
try
{
    await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var ex2 = ex as InvalidApiRequestException;
    if(ex2 != null)
    {
        var x = ex2.Errors;
    }
}
```

[`InvalidApiRequestException` Source](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/SendGrid/SendGridMail/Exceptions/InvalidApiRequestException.cs)

found on: 
http://www.rolandocr.com/2015/06/how-to-using-sendgrid-csharp-library-and-deliverasync-method-error-handling-and-async-pattern/#sthash.1mVXMDWh.dpbs

Comment: thank you, but I would be know a method when I can find original exception itself from code

Comment: could you rephrase your comment?

Comment: If you really want to catch all exceptions, you can do this by using multiple catch blocks. Your way is.... not very good, imho.

i.e. `try
{...}
catch (InvalidApiRequestException e)
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ...
}`

Comment: @OskarHýbl I know how to catch different excepction, I would like to be know how to know all possible exceptions from third-party control. I got that exception and before I have read documentation I did not know about that InvalidApiRequestException

Answer (score 2):

You have to see what is the runtime type of the `Exception` and cast `ex` to that type or define the `catch` as such exception type, for example if the exception if of type `ErrorsException`:

```
try
{
    await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
}
catch (ErrorsException ex)
{
    var errors = ex.Errors
}

classs ErrorsException : Exception
{
    public string[] Errors { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "You have to see what is the runtime type of the Exception and cast ex to that type" - I want to find way to do it :)

Comment: @Oleg Sh: debug your code and when exception is catched in Locals windows of VisualStudio you can see the type of exception or add 'ex' variable to watch windows. Or as CodeNotFound say in the comments move the mouse over ex variable

Comment: @OlegSh by using the debugger. When you look at `ex` in the debugger [the actual type of `ex` will be in a pair of `{ }`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bUsQv.png),